# Laravel 5.6 и Apache 2. Apache не видит маршруты

Tags: laravel, apache, apache2, laravel5

Настроил хост для проекта на Laravel 5.6. Появилась проблема: Apache тупо не видит маршруты(Вообще я хз в чем проблема).То есть у меня есть роуты авторизации, но когда пишу /login выдает Notfound:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда проверяю работу через php sartisan serve он показывает , что все должно работать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю, что сделал не правильно, вот конфигурация хоста для проекта:

    ServerName skyboard.ru

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/skyboard/public

<Directory /var/www/skyboard/public>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#pretty-urls

Comment: @RaZik все равно

Comment: Что все равно? Выложите htaccess с корня проекта. Напишите что вы уже пробовали. Ваш вопрос не ясен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простая ошибка. Сначала нужно включить `mod_rewrite`:

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Затем зайти в конфиг apache:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Ищем настройки для `/var/www` и ставим `AllowOverride All`. После перезапускаем apache и все работает:

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```